# pandas fillna date from another column

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas, data-manipulation

Get my test data:

```
 import pandas as pd

 df =    {'Id': {1762056: 2.0, 1762055: 1.0},
'FillDate': {1762056: Timestamp('2015-08-01 00:00:00'), 1762055:Timestamp('2015-08-01 00:00:00')}, 
 'Date': {1762056: nan, 1762055: nan}, 
 }

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Data looks like:

```
        Id         Date        FillDate
        1.0      NaN         2015-08-01
        2.0      NaN         2015-08-01
```

So to fill missing date, I do:

```
df['Date'].fillna(df['FillDate'], inplace=True)
```

which gives me

```
         Id    Date                  FillDate
        1.0  1438387200000000000  2015-08-01
        2.0  1438387200000000000  2015-08-01
```

how to get `Date` column in date form

Comment: use `pd.to_datetime()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked:

```
 df['Date'].fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['FillDate']).dt.date, inplace=True)
```

which gives

```
      Id    Date       FillDate
      1.0  2015-08-01  2015-08-01
      2.0  2015-08-01  2015-08-01
```

Comment: What version pandas are you using? this works in `0.19.0` it looks like your `dtype` is still numeric so it's casting `datetime` to `ns` values, also the `dt.date` should not be necessary, by default the time component will not be displayed if it's set to `00:00` i.e. blank

Comment: ``pandas==0.18.1``

Comment: I tried without ``dt.date`` before posting the question, didn't work

Comment: I think this is a bug then which has been fixed in latest pandas

Comment: OK can you show what `df.info()` shows from `df['Date'].fillna(df['FillDate'], inplace=True)` it's probably `np.float64`

Comment: Although this is a workaround the `dtype` will be `datetime.date` rather than `datetime64/Timestamp`

Comment: ``df.info()`` output    ``FillDate    2 non-null datetime64[ns]``  (without ``pd.datetime(df['FillDate'])``  as you mentioned.  also, ``dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), object(2)``  and ``Date       2 non-null object``

Comment: Sorry you're saying `df['Date']` is `datetime64` after using `f['Date'].fillna(df['FillDate'], inplace=True)`? If so it must be a display bug that was fixed in `0.19.0`